# Cannot convert '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[AppEvents.ParameterName : Any]'

Tags: swift, facebook

I have used Facebook(Meta) SDK and created parameters as

```
[ AppEvents.ParameterName.content.rawValue: self.content, AppEvents.ParameterName.contentID.rawValue: self.contentId, AppEvents.ParameterName.contentType.rawValue: "", AppEvents.ParameterName.currency.rawValue: self.currency ]
```

But for this created dictionary it is giving me error : -

```
Cannot convert '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[AppEvents.ParameterName : Any]'"
```

It was working previously but from Release version 12.1.0 of Facebook(Meta), library of Facebook(Meta) is giving this error.

Answer (score 1):

In the code above created parameters dictionary having `.rawValue` with every parameter key defined inside dictionary. It has to be removed from here.

Also define it as :-

```
let parameters: [AppEvents.ParameterName : Any] = [ AppEvents.ParameterName.content: self.content, AppEvents.ParameterName.contentID: self.contentId, AppEvents.ParameterName.contentType: "", AppEvents.ParameterName.currency: self.currency ]
```

It will work.